# JS - Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, html

Boa noite!

Estou estudando JS e me deparei com um problema aparentemente comum, mas que não estou conseguindo resolver.

Tenho o JS, onde crio uma variável para o usuário e senha, e coloco no fim o "value" para pegar o valor digitado pelo usuário. Porém sempre me retorna o mesmo erro de "Cannot read property 'value' of null".

Já testei colocando o "value" no meu IF, na função de teste (mesmo colocando valores, o setInterval sempre traz como nulo).

Acredito que seja problema referente a ordem de carregamento da página, mas não sei identificar como resolver o problema

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#logar");
var user = document.getElementById("#usuario").value;
var senha = document.getElementById("#senha").value;

button.onclick = function confirmaLiberacao() {
 if (validarUser(user,senha) == true) {
  window.open('liberado.html');
 } else 
  window.open('negado.html');
};

function teste() {
 console.log(user,senha); 
};

setInterval(teste,3000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Teste</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inter|Roboto+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

 <header></header>

 <main>
  <section class="login">
   <h2>Faça o login ou cadastra-se</h2>
   <form action="/">
    <input type="text" id="usuario" autocomplete="name" placeholder="Usuário ou e-mail" required="required">
    <input type="password" autocomplete="current-password" id="senha" placeholder="Senha" required="required">
    <button class="botao" id="logar">Login</button>
    <button class="botao" id="cadastrar">Cadastrar</button>
   </form>
  </section>
 </main>
 <footer></footer>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../Model/model.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../Controller/controller.js" aynsc></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nas linhas `var user = document.getElementById("#usuario").value;` e `var senha = document.getElementById("#senha").value;` retire o `#` dos parâmetros. Ou se quiser manter o `#` troque o método `getElementById()` por `querySelector()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está na hora de pegar o elemento por *ID*. O programa não está encontrando nenhum *ID* com o nome "*#usuario*" ou "*#senha*". Como ele não encontrou, retornou *null*. E como null não tem função ou atributos, o programa quebrou ao tentar chamar *value* de *null*.

Fizeste certo na primeira linha:

```
var button = document.querySelector("#logar");
```

Porém nas outras, fez algo redundante, pois **#** já significa ID, então a função **getElementById** só precisa do nome sem a cerquilha(#).

**Ficaria assim:**

```
var button = document.getElementById('logar');    
var user = document.getElementById('usuario').value;
var senha = document.getElementById('senha').value;
```

Neste caso ele diz: Quero encontrar o *ID* com nome *usuario*.

Já com o **querySelector**, precisas informar o tipo dele por forma de seletores. O seletor de ID, como foi visto anteriormente, é o **#** (cerquilha).

**Ficaria desta forma:**

```
var button = document.querySelector('#logar');    
var user = document.querySelector('#usuario').value;
var senha = document.querySelector('#senha').value;
```

Bons estudos!